# A regularity type question in integral geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, integral-geometry

The affine projective space  $AP^1$ is the 3 dimensional analytic manifold consists of all lines passing through arbitrary points of the plane.
For an smoith function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ which is integrable along each line in $AP^1$ we have an obvious map $I_f:AP^1\to \mathbb{R}$ via integration along each line.

Assume that $I_f$ is real analytic. Does this implies that $f$ is real analytic too?

Comment: The similar [Radon transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform) may help.